# How to enable the libattr frature(abbreviated xattr) in linux?

Tags: linux, python, attributes

I would use xattr in python, but found the xattr's keys() is empty, does that indicate the libattr feature wasn't enabled? I've learned the libattr feature is disabled in ext3/ext4 by default, but how to enable it? Expect your help! Thank you~

```
>>> import xattr
>>> x = xattr.xattr('tiger_8a428_userdvd.dmg')
>>> x
<xattr file='tiger_8a428_userdvd.dmg'>
>>> x.keys()
[]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must have kernel support for this, and (re)mount the filesystem via `mount -o user_xattr`.  So, try `mount -o remount,user_xattr <device>`.